# how many ast's a llvm program generate?

Tags: llvm

I am reading the llvm's compiler writing guide: 
https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl02.html

In that guide, they are using a simple language called "kaleidoscope" as an example. Before reading that guide, I was under the impression that a single AST is generated for every program (I assume that the program is written on a single file and hence no linking is necessary). But it seems that llvm creates a separate AST for every line (or, to be more precise, for every construct). Hence, for a single program, llvm can create hundreds of separate ast's. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Read up on [trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)). An AST is an Abstract Syntax **Tree,** so each node is itself a (sub-)tree.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that this chapter doesn't really have much to do with LLVM. It's just explaining how to write a parser and an AST for the language. It does not use any code from the LLVM library¹ and wouldn't look any differently in a project that did not use LLVM at all². The LLVM-specific part only comes later when you translate the AST to LLVM IR. So if anything, it's not that LLVM generates "multiple ASTs", it's that the code from the tutorial generates "multiple ASTs".

So is it accurate to say that code generates multiple ASTs? Kind of - it all depends on what exactly you mean by that.

Like any tree, an AST consists of multiple subtrees. Each subtree is itself a valid tree. So you could say that every non-trival tree is in fact a collection of multiple trees and this would apply to the AST in the tutorial as well.

However it's important to note that all of the subtrees are part of the larger tree. It is not true that the code creates multiple trees that aren't connected to each other if that's what you were thinking.

---

¹ Other than `llvm::make_unique`, but that could just as well be replaced with `std::make_unique` if your compiler supports C++14 or your own implementation if it doesn't.

² On a similar note, it is also perfectly possible to write an LLVM-based compiler by generating the LLVM IR directly in the parser and not create any ASTs at all. Whether and how you generate your ASTs is entirely independent from LLVM.